# Strange error when using Pandas to_datetime()

Tags: python, pandas

When i try to format dates using Pandas to_datetime(), i get the error:

**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'**

he following is the code that produced the error :

```
data = pd.read_csv('EURUSD.csv')

data.columns = [['Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vol']]

data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %h:%m%:%S.%f')
```

why isn't it working?

Comment: can you post a fragment of your csv file?

Comment: It looks like you are running different code altogether.

Comment: Gmt time                                 Open High         Low         Close Volume
02.01.2017 00:00:00.000 1.05283 1.05283 1.05282 1.05282 7.2
02.01.2017 00:01:00.000 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 0
02.01.2017 00:02:00.000 1.05283 1.05283 1.05282 1.05282 2.19
02.01.2017 00:03:00.000 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 1.88
02.01.2017 00:04:00.000 1.05283 1.05283 1.05283 1.05283 1.25
02.01.2017 00:05:00.000 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 1.05282 1.88
02.01.2017 00:06:00.000 1.05283 1.05283 1.05282 1.05282 3.44